# Create a Shared Mailbox from a new Synced User Account

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

Is there any way to create a shared mailbox in Office 365, linked to a new synced user account ?

I mean:

1. Create a new user account in Active directory.
2. Sync it to office 365 (Azure AD connect)
3. Set this new synced user account to be a shared mailbox.

Many thanks

***Edit to add more info*** / *** re-edited to update the procedure ****

The only approach I found is first add a Exchange license to the new synced account, and then convert the mailbox to a shared mailbox. But I feel like there's should be a more efficient way to achieve it. This are the steps of this approach:

1. In the 365 admin portal select the new synced user account, for example :

   shared.mailbox.Sales@mydomain.com
2. Add an available exchange license, for example :

   Exchange online Plan 1
3. Convert the mailbox to be a shared mailbox with the cmdlet set-mailbox :

   get-mailbox shared.mailbox.Sales | set-mailbox -type shared
4. Since a shared mailbox don't require a license, you can remove the previously assigned license in the admin 365 admin portal.

The pro's to have the shared mailbox linked to an AD synced account are:

- You have all your accounts in your on premise Active Directory.
- In case you need the shared mailbox to be accessed using a user/password, you can use the active directory user/password and access to it using outlook.office365.com

sources:
http://office365support.ca/create-a-shared-mailbox-from-an-existing-synced-user-account/ 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook/service-accounts-shared-mailbox-with-enabled/0243cceb-35ee-4fed-88b4-908054a95578

Comment: Please update with links to the sources you've already checked and what you've already tried.

Comment: Shared mailboxes aren't tied to a specific AD account

Comment: @colyn1337 I added more info, any considerations are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you need to manage a lot of these mailboxes?
Do you have any Exchange on-prem servers?

An option is to create and manage these mailboxes completely in Office 365. Is there a specific need to have them exist in your AD?

As you've seen, you need to create a licensed mailbox, before you can convert it. To get around this, you can try the "Enable-RemoteMailbox" PowerShell command, and use the "-Room" switch.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607313(v=exchg.150).aspx
 *The Enable-RemoteMailbox cmdlet mail-enables an existing on-premises user. The mail-enabled user contains a specific attribute that indicates that an associated mailbox in the service should be created when the user is synchronized to the service using directory synchronization.*

This article also describes what you want to do, but seems a bit wonky:
https://365lab.net/2014/06/20/exchange-online-how-to-create-a-dirsynced-resource-mailbox/